# Get the url of the full sized attachment image using post ID?

Tags: plugins, posts, attachments, images

I have this function:

```
function get_image_link( &$post ) {
         $image_link_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'as_link_to_image', true ); 

         $image_link_from_post = '';

         if ( function_exists( 'has_post_thumbnail' ) && has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
            $attachment_image_link = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), full );
         }

         if ( $attachment_image_link[0] )
            $image_link_from_post = $attachment_image_link[0];

         if( !empty( $image_link_meta ) ) 
            $final_image_link = $image_link_meta;

         elseif( !empty( $image_link_from_post ) )
            $final_image_link = $image_link_from_post; 

         else
            $final_image_link = WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/link/to/no-image.png';

         return $final_image_link;
    }
}
```

Any idea why `$image_link_from_post` isn't getting a value?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Aside from missing quotes around _full_ and extra bracket at the end this seems to be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be able to return the url of the large image.

```
$largeImg = wp_get_attachment_link( $attachment_id, 'large', false );
```

There's also this incase that doesn't work.

```
wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'large' );
```

Answer (score 2):

Great Snippet available [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/wordpress/get-featured-image-url/) from the guys at CSS-Tricks:

```
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url_array = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id, 'thumbnail-size', true);
$thumb_url = $thumb_url_array[0];
```

When I first tried this solution it kept throwing 'Missing Attachment' because I was referencing the post ID instead of the attachment ID. Anywho this little snippet helped clear that up for me.  First comment reduces it to one line!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This line right here:

```
if ( !$attachment_image_link[0] )
            $image_link_from_post = $attachment_image_link[0];
```

You're only assigning the `$image_link_from_post` variable to the post thumbnail if the post thumbnail does not exist. Take out the NOT operator in the conditional and it should work more the way you intend.

*Update: oops, weird, I just copied that line out of your code, but now its not there. Did you already solve the problem?*

Comment: corrected it.. it was a typo :-)

Comment: Does the function work now for you?

Comment: No, unfortunately..

Comment: In that case I'm not sure. You should quote `'full'` in the call to `get_post_thumbnail_id`. Also, check for `current_theme_supports( 'post-thumbnails' )` rather than `function_exists( 'has_post_thumbnail' )`, that's all I can offer.

Comment: I added support to my theme already particularly in `functions.php`. Thanks for the time!